# Check argument value passed into function in unit test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock v3](http://ocmock.org/reference/) do unit testing, I want to test the following piece of code:

```
@implementation School
-(void) handleStudent:(Student*) student{
 Bool result = [self checkIdentityWithName:student.name age:student.age];
 ...
}
...
@end
```

In my following test case I created a `student` instance with name "John", age 23. and then I run the function under test:

```
-(void) testHandleStudent{
  Student *student = [Student initWithName:@"John" age:23];
  // function under test
  [schoolPartialMock handleStudent:student];

  // I want to not only verify checkIdentityWithName:age: get called, 
  // but also check the exact argument is passed in. that's John 23 in this case
  // how to check argument ? 

}
```

In my test case, I want to verify that the **exact arguments values** are passed into function `checkIdentityWithName:age:` . that's name "John" and age 23 are used. How to verify that in **OCMock v3**? (There is no clear example in its documentation how to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like that

```
-(void) testHandleStudent{
    id studentMock = OCMClassMock([Student class]);
    OCMStub([studentMock name]).andReturn(@"John");
    OCMStub([studentMock age]).andReturn(23);

    [schoolPartialMock handleStudent:studentMock];
    OCMVerify([schoolPartialMock checkIdentityWithName:@"John" age:23]);
}
```

or

```
-(void) testHandleStudent{
        id studentMock = OCMClassMock([Student class]);
        OCMStub([studentMock name]).andReturn(@"John");
        OCMStub([studentMock age]).andReturn(23);

        OCMExpect([schoolPartialMock checkIdentityWithName:@"John" age:23]);

        [schoolPartialMock handleStudent:studentMock];

        OCMVerifyAll(schoolPartialMock);
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks, I'd like to see any other answer could provides a solution to capture the argument on the fly with OCMock 3. If impossible, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks but If you look OCMock 3 documentation the answer that i provided  matches this documentation and syntaxis.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you really want to capture the arguments to do asserts then you have to use blocks using `andDo`. In that case you have to take extra care with scoping of variables and with retaining the arguments pulled from the invocation. Questions have been asked (and answered!) around this before.

Comment: Helped to get an idea for my scenario, thanks very much !